# MeshRegion automatically merges vertices that have the same position in space

Tags: mesh

I sometimes work with surface meshes that have self-intersections ([immersions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_(mathematics)) rather than embeddings). `MeshRegion` usually doesn't have any problems dealing with these kinds of surfaces, *unless* there are distinct vertices that have the same position in space. During the construction of a `MeshRegion` these vertices are automatically merged together (the problem remains if I import such a mesh), and this obviously messes with the combinatorics of the surface. Is there a way to disable this undesired "feature"?

Here is an example illustrating this problem:

```
n = 31;
uvs = Flatten[Table[{i, j}/(n - 1), {i, 0, n - 1}, {j, 0, n - 1}], 1];

immersion[{u_, v_}] := {Cos[2 \[Pi] u], Sin[2 \[Pi] u], v/4};
cylinderpts = immersion /@ uvs;

foldoverimmersion[{u_, v_}] := {Cos[1/4 \[Pi] (1 + 6 u)]/(
   1 + Sin[1/4 \[Pi] (1 + 6 u)]^2), (
   Cos[1/4 \[Pi] (1 + 6 u)] Sin[1/4 \[Pi] (1 + 6 u)])/(
   1 + Sin[1/4 \[Pi] (1 + 6 u)]^2), v/4};
foldoverpts = foldoverimmersion /@ uvs;

idx[{i_, j_}] := n (i - 1) + j;
faces = Map[idx, 
   Flatten[Table[{{{i, j}, {i + 1, j}, {i, j + 1}}, {{i + 1, 
        j}, {i + 1, j + 1}, {i, j + 1}}}, {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, 1, 
      n - 1}], 2], {2}];
meshfaces = Polygon /@ faces;

parameterM = MeshRegion[uvs, meshfaces]
cylinderM = MeshRegion[cylinderpts, meshfaces]
foldoverM = MeshRegion[foldoverpts, meshfaces]
```

[image: MeshRegion automatically merges nearby vertices]

The meshes `parameterM`, `cylinderM`, and `foldoverM` are constructed using the same list of faces, but running `MeshCellCount` yields

```
{961, 2760, 1800}
{930, 2730, 1800}
{930, 2730, 1800}
```

It might seem reasonable that the nearby vertices should be merged for the cylinder. On the other hand, the example where I extruded part of a lemniscate (`foldoverM`) the vertices are only merged if the grid width is divisible by 6 (since the parameterization I use has self intersections at u=1/6 and u=5/6).

Comment: The mesh cell count is identical. But it make sense, that the count of edges and points is less when you connect faces and points.

Comment: I didn’t connect the faces and points (the number of input vertices is the same). It is strange that the geometry of the surface (vertex positions) changes the topology (faces/combinatorics) of the underlying mesh... if I take a piece of paper and fold it in half it doesn’t collapse into an unfolded piece of paper of half the size (MeshRegion will collapse the paper if the the triangulation is symmetric across the seam).

Comment: Hi, am I mistaken, if I think that at the "seam", where you connect  left side of the mesh to the right side to form a cylinder, you are identifying edges and vertices. Therefore, their number will be reduced. Similar thing with the foldover.

Comment: In the description of the faces that I give I am not explicitly identifying the vertices and edges, and I want to make sure that MeshRegion does not automatically identify them based on their vertex positions. I guess another way to ask the question (which may help me understand the general case) is to ask how would I represent a cylinder with a seam (ofc, without changing the positions)?

Comment: If I set n=5 and look at "cylinderpts" then there are 5 duplicated points. If you do not want to "close" the cylinder ", you may e.g. say: immersion[{u_, v_}] := {Cos[2 \[Pi] u  0.95], Sin[2 \[Pi] u], v/4};

Comment: Of course you can move the points apart, but unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for. Again, I want to reiterate that the points are not duplicated. They have the same vertex positions, but different vertex labels (is that distinction clear?). The real examples I am interested in are anyways much more complicated and can't be resolved how you suggest.

Comment: I think MMA is clever enough to identify points that have identical coordinates. If you are not doing this, you are putting geometry upside down. But if you really want to do this, I think the right way to do this would be to introduce an additional dimension.

Comment: It is clever only for some applications... if you think about geometry only as the geometry of the subset in R^3 then this is fine. However, from the point of view of (discrete) differential geometry this is completely backwards. If you look at the Wikipedia page for an immersion you can see the Morin surface which has a triple point intersection, even though the surface topologically is a sphere. In my research certain special triangulations play an important role and so I can’t always remesh the geometry to make sure that the points with multiplicity are not vertices in my triangulation.

Comment: Well, what happens if the line of intersection does not belong to your vertices nor edges? But I nevertheless think MMA does the right thing in merging points and edges. In your case it is not the searched for behavior, but in most other applications it  is what is expected.

Comment: In that case, MeshRegion behaves as expected and does not change the combinatorics. For example, if you take n = 30 then you will see that the foldover mesh example has a line of self intersection but the vertices are not merged together. That is basically the behavior that I want to retain for surfaces in these special/degenerate configurations:)